# touchesBegan is not triggered

Tags: iphone

I used the codes below to detect touch on the object

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSArray *allTouches = [touches allObjects];

    for (UITouch *touch in allTouches)
    {
           NSLog(@"TOUCH DETECT");

    }
}
```

but it is not triggered

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What kind of object? `touchesBegan:withEvent:` is only called for UIResponder subclasses.

Also, if it's a UIView, make sure `userInteractionEnabled` is YES.